# Spring boot admin - register two instances of the same app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I would like to register two instances of the same application (only port is different) in spring boot admin server. But I see only one instance (MyApp instance 2) in my spring boot admin panel. What's wrong in my config?

Basic info:

- Spring boot admin client - 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
- Spring boot admin server - 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
- Spring boot version (both) - 2.0.1.RELEASE

My application.yml file:

```
spring:
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        url: http://example.org:7474/admin/
        instance:
          name: 'MyApp instance 1'
          service-url: http://example.org:7474/MyApp/
          service-base-url: http://example.org:7474/
          metadata:
            user.name: myuser
            user.password: mypassword
        instance:
          name: 'MyApp instance 2'
          service-url: http://example.org:27474/MyApp/
          service-base-url: http://example.org:27474/
          metadata:
            user.name: myuser
            user.password: mypassword
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS
```

Comment: how are you registering your both apps ?

Comment: @Mehraj Malik, I used config like above. Next I deploy the same war file into two tomcat instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the Spring Boot Admin Client is capable to do a single registration.

I think it's rather unusual to register the same instance twice (as your config tries to do)

If you include the client in each of the instances to register it works.